# Github for Windows gui + Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I'm Switching from svn to git for couple of projects that will need to be published on GitHub.
I have a brand new Java project on my workspace, (Eclipse ide), and its under version control (Git), i have a local git repository under D:\repository.
Remotely (on github) i have created a new empty project.
Now, i have downloaded the github gui for windows, and i have (i think succesfully) let the gui to recognize my local repository (i see the little screen icon on the left and all source code on the right), but how can i upload the entire project to github via the gui?

The docs in the help pages of the gui do not (surprisingly) explain this.
Also, is it possible that whenever i commit a new change, the changes are pushable via the gui to github? 
Thx

Answer (score 0):

Do some changes and it will show "uncommited changes". Click on it and type in the message, press "commit to [branch]".
Then just press the Sync button on the top right.

[See this link](https://help.github.com/articles/synchronizing-repositories)